# Rails production app with nginx and passenger 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am trying to run my rails app in a Ubuntu 16.04 vps but i am getting "We're sorry , but something went wrong (500)

in /var/log/nginx/error.log i get this

```
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6776 2071/T5 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:588 ]: 
Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more 
time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6777 2071/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1002 ]:       
Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients 
have disconnected...
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6779 2071/Ta Ser/Server.h:886 ]: [ApiServer] 
Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6779 2071/Ta Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [ApiServer] 
Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6783 2071/T5 Ser/Server.h:886 ]: [ServerThr.1] 
Freed 128 spare client objects
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6783 2071/T5 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [ServerThr.1] 
Shutdown finished

[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6800 2077/T3 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:430 ]: 
Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more 
time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6801 2077/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:500 ]:  
Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients 
have disconnected...
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6802 2077/T5 Ser/Server.h:886 ]: 
[UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6802 2077/T5 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: 
[UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6805 2077/T3 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouter]  
Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.6806 2077/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:531 ]: 
Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:14.7004 2071/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: 
Passenger core shutdown finished
2017/09/10 05:06:15 [info] 2131#2131: Using 32768KiB of shared memory 
for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:15.7729 2137/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1283 ]: 
Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:15.7853 2140/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1083 ]: 
Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:15.7855 2140/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:248 ]: 
Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:15.7901 2140/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:830 ]: 
Passenger core online, PID 2140
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:15.8015 2146/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:537 ]: 
Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:15.8025 2146/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:350 ]: 
Passenger UstRouter online, PID 2146
[ N 2017-09-10 05:06:18.2497 2140/T8 
age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no 
update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 2165 stdout:
App 2165 stderr: sh: 1:
App 2165 stderr: env: not found
App 2165 stderr:
App 2179 stdout:
```

I've been chasing this for hours, any direction is much appreciated, let me know if i need to post more things.

EDIT:
here is my nginx.conf file and my virtual host file. I am trying to connect my servers ip right now

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 
text/javascript;

##
# Phusion Passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
##

include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at: 
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php; 
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER"; 
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";   
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#  
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;  
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

And

```
server{
listen 80; 

server_name ip;

root /var/www/chads_photos/public;

passenger_enabled on;
passenger_ruby /home/webmaster/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby;

passenger_env_var SECRET_KEY_BASE secret;
passenger_env_var CHAD_DB_USERNAME user;
passenger_env_var CHAD_DB_PASSWROD pass;

}
```

Comment: Post your `nginx.conf` also are you using environment variables? You need to use `passenger_env_var` for the same. See https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var

Comment: updated with my nginx.conf. i am using environment variables, i tried passenger_env_var with the same results. thank you for you suggestion

Comment: Can you try adding `passenger_load_shell_envvars off;`

Comment: I've tested it in development and it works perfect, is there anything i need to change for production.

Comment: So you mean the issue is resolved?

Comment: it is now, thank you for your help the main issue that caused all of my problems was a small typo, thank you again

Comment: What typo? So we also know what me missed picking up

Comment: typo in CHAD_DB_PASSWROD suppose to be CHAD_DB_PASSWORD

Comment: Lol! that was a bad one. Glad you picked it